# How to add authorization in express routes?

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say i have several routes in express like,

```
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/blogs', blog);
app.use('/news', news);
app.use('/profile', profile);
```

Here, login, blog, news, profile is routes .js files which contains different get/post routes. I.E. `/blogs/new` or `blogs/:id/edit` etc.

Suppose I have 2 users in my system, A and B.
A can access `/blogs` and `/news` but can't access `/profile`
B can access `/profile` but not the other two.
And `/login` can be accessed by any user.

How do i do this with express and node?

Is there any way i can set a user to be permitted only to access `/profile` route and it's children route?

P.S i don't want to use passport.

Comment: Use Passport or something like it. Writing your own is really hard and if you get it wrong you'll just make a huge mess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) for this purpose. Here is an example code for adding passport to your application.

1)Add following lines to packages.json

```
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-jwt": "^3.0.1",
```

2). And the following code in server.js. Passport.js has multiple strategies for authentication. Here is configuration for `jwt`

```
var passport = require('passport');
app.use(passport.initialize());
require('./server/config/passport')(passport);
var auth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });

app.use('/your/path/*', auth, function (req, res, next) {
  next();
});
```

Passport with check all the paths like `/your/path/*` ( i hope you know that).

Answer (score 0):

I will demonstrate this with the cookie session. first lets set up a session. i will be using mongod, for different databases, express-session has different packages to save the session.

```
//------ app.js----------
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoDbStore = require("connect-mongodb-session")(session);
const store = new MongoDbStore({
  uri: "mongodb://localhost:27017/yilmaz",
  collection: "sessions",
});
//  ------ this adds "session" property to the req

 app.use(
  session({
    secret: "anyhting long",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store,
  })
);
```

First step of authentication is signing up. We save user's email and password. Next step user logs in the system. In this step we check if the email (or username) and password are in match.

```
exports.postLogin = async (req, res, next) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) {
    return res.redirect("/login");
  }
  const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if (match) {
    // when we protect the routes we look at this property
    // session property is attached by the express-session
    // -------THIS IS WHERE WE SAVE THE SESSION TO DATABASE
    req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
    req.session.user = user;
    // after req.session.user is set, everytime client makes a request, our middleware will be checking this
    return req.session.save((err) => {
      console.log("error in postLogin", err);
      return res.redirect("/");
    });
  }
  res.redirect("/login");
};

with checking `req.session.isLoggedin` you can write a middleware and used on the routes.



module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.session.isLoggedin) {
    return res.redirect("/login");
  }
  next();
};
```

in any route you want u can add this middleware

```
const isAuth = require("../middleware/is-auth");

router.get("/edit-product/:productId", isAuth, adminController.getEditProduct);
```